# Asp.net Mvc - Need help understanding how to display header content when user is authenticated / not authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net mvc 4.

I have a header with two sections, top and bottom.    The top section simply displays static links and images.

The bottom section will show a login button and other information when a user is not logged in.

Once the user logs in the bottom section will show user specific information and overall game play information.  I want to reload this information whenever a user makes a request to a page on the site and I determine the data is stale.

Using asp.net web forms I could create a user control to represent the bottom sections functionality.

It appears in asp.net mvc I can use partial views and then call RenderAction which would allow a controller action to be called when rendering the bottom section.

In the controller action I could  render one partial view for authenticated users and another partial view for unauthenticated users.    I could also reload the data for authenticated users if it is determined to be stale.

Is this the best approach?    I don't need ajax for my bottom section.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the complexity of your bottom section. If there's not much logic, you can put authenticated and unauthenticated html code in a single partial view. If they are quite different, use two separated partial views is OK. Also, simply put button section into your master page is also a common practice, there'are no quite differences.

If you leverage .net mvc's authentication framework(which should be best practice), you can simply use **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** in your Action. In View page it's **Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated**. It can check whether current user has signed in.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways and it all depends what kind of Authorization mechanism you're using.
The general rule is that you query (pseudo code here)
@if(IsAuthenticated(currentUser)
{
 bla bla
}
else
non authenticated content

Take a look at this project with sample and documentation
http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

It will drive you through what you are trying to accomplish.